# How to subscribe to liveChatMessage events in real time

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to write a chat bot to forward messages from my live chat into the game I'm playing so I can read them and respond to my audience when I stream, however, it looks like my bot is running into quota exceeded errors.

I could not find a way to subscribe to a message event, so for testing I polled the liveChatMessages resource once a second, which however quickly pushed my over my daily quota.

Obviously it's important for my bot to process messages in near real-time, otherwise I won't be able to properly interact with my audience, but I assume I've simply glossed over a detail in the API documentation. What is the expected / suggested way of processing chat messages from my live chat in real time without exceeding my quota within a couple of hours?

Comment: Note the existence of [`pollingIntervalMillis`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#pollingIntervalMillis) field. But as far as I know it will anyway consume all your daily quota, the only official solution consists in requesting [a quota extension](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison thanks, I suppose I could add that. I also see that there is a lot of info in the general Data API documentation that isn't present in the Live Streaming API documentation. I also see that using part and fields, if I understand this correctly I'm able to quite substantially reduce the amount of quota a single read takes. Does that apply here too? So could I only request the bare minimum (message ID, message timestamp, message text, author ID, author name) and have a lot less to worry about? For a LIVE chat API this daily quota seems pretty tight.

Comment: Using `part` and `fields` doesn't reduce the quota usage, the quota usage only depends on the number of HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, this API is useless for chat integration with current quota limits, as I am trying to do the same thing. Requested an increase, guess I'll see what comes back.